# Raspberry pi hangs

Tags: raspbian

i made a stupid mistake while following through this tutorial http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Web-Server/step9/Install-an-FTP-server/ I did not log in as root or whatsoever and i get locked out and I cant do anything on command line. When I tried to access the file manager to manually change the file, R-Pi runs on full load (FULL GREEN BAR!) and I'm so scared!! What should I do now? I don't dare to reset it. I might lose all work :( What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Okay problem solved after 37 minutes of troubleshooting. 
I logged in remotely through SSH as root.

```
login as: root
password: <root password>
```

change back the passwd file which caused the problem

find the line `#pi:x;1000:1000:Raspberry Pi User,,,:home/pi:/bin/bash`
and change it to `pi:x;1000:1000:Raspberry Pi User,,,:home/pi:/bin/bash`